# When I should not define default props in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a question because I can not find any advanced articles about it.

Where I should or shouldn't define defaultProps?

Should I define it in utils function also?

I read that Dan Abramov told, that probably in future defaultProps will be deprecated...

It is better to use some condition (if else) than default props?

In my opinion, there is no sense to define defaultProps with null values or empty objects/array in case no values in props and in this case using if/else conditions.

There is only one situation, where we can define it - if BUSINESS LOGIC define default values.

Comment: The [eventual deprecation](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1133878326358171650?s=20) is presumably because you can just use default function arguments instead. Whether you should or shouldn't set those values for a given situation is orthogonal to how you decide to set them if you do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the idea of `defaultProps` is bad. The current syntax kinda is.

Fortunately there is a better and more concise way now:

```
export const myComponent = (props) =>
{
  const { color = "red" } = props; // sets color to "red" if color is not defined
}
```

In general, default props are a good way to make your components customizable but also easy to use, since you don't have to define every value by yourself everytime.